Export uses relative paths and does not automatically create subdirectories
Exporting using relative paths does not automatically create subdirectories.But using absolute path export, you can directly create subdirectories
Create a tmp directory in the current directory, export data to tmp, and export data to tmp/123
public ❯ \d
+------------+
| table_name |
+------------+
| air        |
+------------+
Query took 0.058 seconds.
public ❯ copy into 'tmp' from air file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 11   |
+------+
Query took 0.024 seconds.
public ❯ copy into 'tmp/123' from air file_format = (type = 'csv');
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: IO error: No such file or directory (os error 2)"}

But when I export using absolute path, the subdirectory is automatically created
public ❯ copy into 'file:///tmp/123' from air file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 11   |
+------+
Query took 0.011 seconds.
public ❯ copy into 'file:///tmp' from air file_format = (type = 'csv');
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 11   |
+------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.

Has anyone encountered this problem?
